# Which US Apple Store iPad Pro supports mmWave?

Tags: ipad, apple-store

I can't seem to find in the store listings the specific option that includdes mmwave - it seems that iPad Pro + Cellular has both that and +mmWave - which is the exact product that supports mmwave and how do you know for sure in advance?

https://support.apple.com/kb/SP883?locale=en_US

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201471

Answer (score 4):

#### All iPad Pro Cellular Models Support mmWave

The mm bands are the frequencies that exist between 10GHz and 300GHz. This is on the upper end (aka high band) of the 5G spectrum. To know if your device (not just limited to iPhones/iPads) supports mmWave, they have to support the following bands as defined by the [3GPP](https://www.3gpp.org/)

| Band | F (GHz) |
| --- | --- |
| n257 | 28 |
| n258 | 26 |
| n259 | 42 |
| n260 | 39 |
| n261 | 28 |

Source:  [5G mmWave Frequencies](https://https:/https://www.5gmmwave.com/5g-mmwave-frequency-bands/)

Per the [Technical Specifications](https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/specs/) of the iPad Pro, all of them support the sub-6GHz and mmWave bands.  Two models, the A2435 and A2764 only support a subset of these bands - n258, n260, n261.  These are usually devices sold by carriers like T-Mobile in the US

Answer (score 0):

From your links it seems like you're looking at the 12.9" 6th Gen iPad Pro. In that case you want to look for model A2437 to get the one with cellular mmWave support.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the Apple website does not specifically list which iPad Pro + Cellular models support mmWave. However, according to an [Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211828), the iPad Pro models with 5G support include both sub-6GHz and mmWave frequencies. This means that any iPad Pro + Cellular model should support mmWave if it also supports 5G.

To confirm if a specific iPad Pro + Cellular model supports mmWave, you can check the [technical specifications](https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/specs/) on Apple's website or contact Apple support for more information.